# Apache Drill - Using Multiple Delimiters in File Storage Plugin?

Tags: hadoop, apache-drill

I have logs that resemble the following:

```
value1 value2 "value 3 with spaces" value4
```

using:

```
  "formats": {
    "csv": {
      "type": "text",
      "delimiter": " "
    }
  }
```

for the storage plugin delimiting by " " gives me the following columns:

```
columns[0] | columns[1] | columns[2] | columns[3] | columns[5] | columns[6] | columns[7]
value1     | value2     | value      | 3          | with       | spaces     | value4
```

what I'd like is:

```
columns[0] | columns[1] | columns[2]              | columns[3] 
value1     | value2     | value 3 with spaces     | value4
```

Comment: There's a feature targeted for release soon (my educated guess is December) that should work for you: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-3423

Comment: @catpaws is this resolved in 1.3?

Comment: Sorry, it's not in 1.3. The target for DRILL-3423 is 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no way to skip delimiters in Drill. However, if variable 3 is the only one that can have those " " in between, a workaround I can think of is:

- structure your first query so that columns[3] is always the last, Ex

> select  columns[0], columns[1], columns[2], columns[4], columns[3] from dfs.default./path/to/your/file;

- use the CONCATENATE() command to build your variable in a separate column.

Another way around it would require changing the default delimiter in the file prior having Drill reading it. Depending on where you are ingesting your data from this may be feasible or not.

Good luck and if you are looking for more things on Drill, be sure to check out MapR's Community page on Drill, which has code examples that might be helpful: https://community.mapr.com/community/products/apache-drill